# Why can't I call this function?

Tags: coffeescript

This is getting ridiculous...

Why do I get an error when I try to do this?

```
#...codecodecode...

g = generateGuid()

#...codecodecode...

generateGuid = ->
  "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".replace /[xy]/g, (c) ->
    r = Math.random() * 16 | 0
    v = (if c is "x" then r else (r & 0x3 | 0x8))
    v.toString 16
```

All I want to do is call a private function...

Comment: Please include error messages/details in the post, as well as choosing a more applicable title and description of the desired behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

driis is correct. To expand on his answer: You may be used to the JavaScript idiom

```
function generateGuid() { ... }
```

which allows you to call `generateGuid` from anywhere within its scope (even before its definition). CoffeeScript doesn't do this; instead, it compiles to

```
var generateGuid = function() { ... }
```

There are several reasons for doing this, but the long and short of it is that functions obey the same scoping rules as all other variables. Before a value has been assigned to `generateGuid`, `generateGuid()` is an attempt to call `undefined`.

Note that, due to the way asynchronous callbacks work in JavaScript, this will work:

```
setTimeout (->
  g = generateGuid
  # ...codecodecode...
), 0

generateGuid = -> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call the function before it's defined. [This works](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3agenerateGuid%20=%20-%3E%0A%20%20%22xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx%22.replace%20/%5Bxy%5D/g,%20%28c%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20r%20=%20Math.random%28%29%20%2a%2016%20%7C%200%0A%20%20%20%20v%20=%20%28if%20c%20is%20%22x%22%20then%20r%20else%20%28r%20&%200x3%20%7C%200x8%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20v.toString%2016%0A%0Ag%20=%20generateGuid%28%29%0Aalert%20g):

```
#...codecodecode...

#...codecodecode...

generateGuid = ->
  "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".replace /[xy]/g, (c) ->
    r = Math.random() * 16 | 0
    v = (if c is "x" then r else (r & 0x3 | 0x8))
    v.toString 16

g = generateGuid()
```

In case this is surprising to you, remember that Coffeescript compiles to Javascript - in fact, it is not much more than syntactic sugar over some Javascript. Most of the rules that apply in Javascript will also hold true in Coffeescript.

Comment: except that in javascript calling a function before it's defined *works*, because of function hoisting